# How do you determine whether an identifier is referencing something with a NULL value?

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child

My application consists of pairs of classes that have parent/child relationships in the way that the **child class has one parent object member**, and the **parent class has a list of child objects member** (for my simplified example below I am only using single objects however). The information for these classes is fetched from the database, getting the respective parent/child objects simultaneously. This becomes a problem when getting the parent object results in it getting its child objects, resulting in all the child objects getting their parent objects, resulting in.. well, you get the idea.

To hinder this loop I am using an optional parameter for any related object in the method that fetches an object. This parameter is assigned when one of the objects wants to fetch its relative. **I want to know if it is possible to check if "parent" or "child" in my example below are referencing something, despite the referenced object being NULL**. I assume this would work with pointers in C++, but C# is pointerless as far as I know. :(

```
class ParentClass
{
    ChildClass _child;

    public ParentClass(ChildClass child)
    {
        _child = child;
    }
}

class ChildClass
{
    ParentClass _parent;

    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }
}

public static class ItemGetter
{
    public static ChildClass GetChild(ParentClass parent = null)
    {
        ChildClass c = null;

        // Here I want to check if 'parent' is referencing anything, regardless of null value.
        ParentClass p = parent ?? GetParent(c);

        c = new ChildClass(p);

        return c;
    }

    public static ParentClass GetParent(ChildClass child = null)
    {
        ParentClass p = null;

        // Here I want to check if 'child' is referencing anything, regardless of null value.
        ChildClass c = child ?? GetChild(p);

        // References to itself as being the parent.
        p = new ParentClass(c);

        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. A reference can be `null` or not. What do you mean when you say "I want to check if 'parent' is referencing anything, regardless of null value"? If `parent` is `null`, your child doesn't reference a parent, otherwise it does.

Comment: Side note: This is **not** the right approach, but you're incorrect on C# not having [pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: check like this if(parent != null) then do something ELSE it was NULL...

Comment: FYI, C# isn't pointerless: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: This is specific to your database retrieval mechanism. How does your database store the relationships? Does it retrieve a foreign key to the parent/child to later retrieve the actual object? In that case, you need to act *after* the keys (and other simple properties) are loaded, but *before* the referenced objects are fetched. In general, you'll need to keep a temporary map of already fetched objects to make sure two children of the same parent are correctly initialized to point to the *same* fetched parent object.

Comment: I had no idea C# used pointers. When was this implemented?

Comment: The classes more or less reflect relationships in my database. So the parent/child relationship is from the database POW rows in different tables connected by a foreign key. The issue here is that the parents/children have to be sent with the contructor of their related object, otherwise it would be simple.

Comment: What does this have to do with WPF?

Comment: Also, simplicity is beauty. Stop trying to reinvent the Wheel and use Entity Framework (or any other ORM)

Comment: @firant - again, so long as we're clear that pointers are *not* the way to solve this problem - C# has had pointers since version 1.

Comment: Strange. I remember back when I started using C# how everyone was all 'it doesn't use pointers' and I didn't even question that. I feel stupid now, ha.

@HighCore - If there's one thing I hate, it's auto generated code. And WPF because my application uses WPF, but you're right, doesn't really relate to this issue.

Comment: @firant PFFF.... ok... stick with your pointers and move bytes here and there in memory... I prefer to develop software instead.

Comment: @firant and don't blame the framework or the tools when it takes you 40 years to build a running application.

Comment: @HighCore And I prefer not having my hand held all the time. :) Your comments don't really help, stay on topic please.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first assumption is not proper:

> This becomes a problem when getting the parent object results in it
>   getting its child objects, resulting in all the child objects getting
>   their parent objects, resulting in.. well, you get the idea.

It will not be problem, since in memory only one instance of the same object will exist. You will only have references of objects in parent object and child objects; not the actual objects. So it is safe to have references even it seems like an infinite loop.

you need to fetch a parent object with it's child entities; you do not need to make any checks.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that the methods will call eachother infinitly until the application crashes, since I need the parent or child reference to be recognized in order to stop one method from calling another.

Comment: why methods are calling each other and where?